# knockout.js, breeze and dynatree/fancytree

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze, dynatree

This is really tricky to get my head around as I'm not used to this style of programming/data management.

All I'm trying to do at the moment is pass a json object returned via breeze into a dynatree or fancytree.

The examples that exist online all assume that the tree will do the ajax call via "initajax" or that some weirdly convoluted custom binding handler is needed into which various objects are passed:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dynatree = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(element).dynatree({
                noLink: true, // noLink is required to 'unlock' the checkboxes
                minExpandLevel: 2
            })
            // the timeout value shows the correct knockout bindings BEFORE dynatree kicks in.
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

This all seems too complicated to me, surely?  I already have the json object, I know that's working.  If I use knockout to "foreach" bind it to some plain html then all data is displayed just fine.  In my mind all I need to do is initialize the tree div and pass it the json object...  It's just that I have no idea how to do that!

I've tried using the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/UhA3m/5/ but chrome developer tools complain about the element having no "dynatree" method when the custom binding handler fires.  It's passing in a "ul" element and that could be the problem - surely it should be passing in the tree div, not the ul element?

Anyhow, if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd hugely appreciate it.  As I'm using John Papa's SPA methodology, I'm also unsure as to where I would put any separate js initialization code as the underlying viewmodel isn't the right place for me to be doing a $(#tree).dynatree initialization type call, is it?  I must admit I've not got my head around this yet.

I suppose all I'm looking for is something along the lines of "once the viewmodel for this view has finished loading and the knockout binding is being done, initialize the dynatree div and pass this json object to the tree" if that makes sense in pseudocode?

Comment: Using fancytree as a connected view in an MVC framework is surely an interesting use case. I have no experience with knockout / breeze, but let me know if can help with improving the tree APIs. For example the applyPatch() methods were created with this in mind. (Disclaimer: I am the author of Dyna-/Fancytree)

Comment: Thanks Martin.  The few people I've seen try to hook it up do something with a custom binding handler (http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/UhA3m/5/). Do you have any examples where dyna/fancytree is initialized with a javascript object (not a json file, an in-memory object array).  I've seen a few examples where a reload is done but not an initialize.  Is it possible to do?  Mind you, the mvvm methodology doesn't really lend itself to direct javascripting apparently which is why people are trying the custom binding handler approach shown in that jsfiddle I linked to.

Comment: tree.reload() accepts a 'source' parameter, that may be an array of child nodes (or a URL, ...). Also the 'source' init option accepts such arrays.

Comment: Well I've been at this all weekend and I can't get it to work.  I'm using the exact code as shown in the fiddle linked to above (http://jsfiddle.net/Ebram/UhA3m/5/) and yet I still get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dynatree'" on the "$(element).dynatree({" line in the custom binding handler.  I can see in Chrome's dev tools that the dynatree script file is loaded ok so I have absolutely no idea what is causing this. I imagine it's to do with durandal and require.js and the AMD pattern that exists in the app I'm doing.

Comment: Aha. Progress!  I had forgotten to include "jquery-ui..." in my bundleconfig.  Error has gone away now, proceeding with further testing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can hopefully point you in the approximate right direction.

It seems dynatree can also take JSON from a file as well as an AJAX request.  In this example [Lazy Loading](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-lazy.html), if you look in the source code, there's:

```
    // In real life we would call a URL on the server like this:
...
      // .. but here we use a local file instead:
```

Storing your data in a file to get it in seems awfully wasteful.  Now that we know it's a little flexible in what it gets, let's see where it uses the data and maybe we can get it to use a local variable instead.  let see where it loads it

Looking in the dynatree source, there's a function associated with `appendAjax`. (line 1774 in my source.)  A little short on time at the moment, but I'd find where it gets the JSON and what it does with it.  Perhaps you can do the same thing outside or mod the handling of `ajaxOptions` to take a variable with the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the input Mark.  I think my problem is more fundamental than that in that I don't yet understand where in the viewmodel to put such code.  Another answer I got on the durandal forum recommends that the best way to do this is using the custom binding handler on knockout, which looks pretty complicated to me and, as I said, doesn't work for me at the moment so I need to experiment more with that I think.